# Rename all Java classes in a package (In Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to rename all the classes in package with a single command.
Right now , My class names are like com.abc.Class1/com.abc.Class2.
Now I am copying all these classes under a new package com.xyx....In class definition I have changed the names using "File search" ...So now How can I change the names under my package (One command for all classes under package "xyz").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, you want to move our classes to another package. For this, click on the package in the project explorer and press **Shift+Alt+R** to rename it, effectively moving all included classes to the new package. This will not affect the names of the classes

**EDIT** A class name prefix? It's at least highly unusual. Eclipse can not help you with these. But if you are on a linux machine, you could do a mass move from command line.  I am not fluent with it myself, so here is a [**mmv tutorial**](http://linux.dsplabs.com.au/mmv-copy-append-link-move-multiple-files-under-linux-shell-bash-by-wildcard-patterns-p5/).

Comment: Thanks...See my class names are (Fully qualified name) com.abc.com_abc_class1.java/com.abc.com_abc_class2.java.Now if i am moving these to package "xyz", Then eclipse can take care of making it to com.xyx.com_abc_class1.java...I WANT IT TO BE it renamed to com.xyx.com_xyz_class1.java

Comment: @VirendraJoshi - I see, this makes it more complicated. Please see the edit

Answer (score 2):

Try some as this, move and then rename all files in a directory:

```
import java.io.File;

    public class Ls {
        public static void main(String args[]) 
        {
            String[] dir = new java.io.File("test").list();
            java.util.Arrays.sort(dir); 
            File f[] = new File("test").listFiles();
            int len1 = dir.length;
            for (int i=0;i<len1; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(dir[i]);
                String name = f[i].getName();
                System.out.println(name);
                int j=name.indexOf('.');
                System.out.println(j);
                String newname = name.substring(0,j) + "_BS" + name.substring(j,name.length()); 
                System.out.println(newname);
                File newFileName=new File(f[i].getParentFile(), newname);
                System.out.println("newFileName="+newFileName);
                f[i].renameTo(newFileName);   
            }
        }   
    }
```